# Where does the name TO-220 come from?

Tags: components

Where does the name TO-220 come from, and what significance does it have, if any? I am aware it is a JEDEC standard but wonder what is the origin of the package name?

Comment: Just to clarify are you asking why JEDEC called that particular package a TO-220? The TO stands for "transistor outline" and I suspect the 220 is just a sequential number allocated to their standards, but maybe someone will know for sure how that side of things works.

Comment: Your question no verb and also missing antecedent. I can't tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

(Wow - this is a tough crowd this morning!)

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-92), of the TO-92 case, "The JEDEC TO-92 descriptor is derived from the original full name for the package: Transistor Outline Package, Case Style 92.", which would lend credence to @PeterJ's speculation that the numeric part is a serial number assigned to the design.

Comment: What happened to TO-93, TO-94, ..., TO-219? :)

Comment: @Johan.A: Same thing that happened to preparations A through G.

Comment: @Johan.A: Same thing that happened to 1-up thru 6-up

Answer (score -4):

Its a transistor package standard. A datasheet will contain all information on performance and available packages from certain vendor.[image]

..."why JEDEC called that particular package a TO-220" why my mom called me Andrew :)

Comment: You answered the question "What is a TO-220", but that is not the question that was asked.

Comment: Had this been a less polite site, this post would have triggered a list of ”your mom” comments. This post does not even attempt to answer the question asked. Voting to delete.